# Sending a message from a nodejs server to a windows machine

Tags: .net, windows, node.js, azure

I have a windows virtual machine and a nodejs server, the nodejs server is not on my virtual machine, what are the possibilities to send a .NET application that is on my virtual machine a string message from the nodejs server, so that my .NET application reacts upon the content of that message?

i am not sure where to start the only thing i could think of is writing that message to a database and let my .NET application check the database every 5 seconds.

How would you solve this problem?

Comment: Why don't you just use sockets

Comment: Where is the node server running?

Comment: @WiredPrairie on another windows virtual machine on azure

Comment: Instead of polling, you might want to just push data directly: http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/08/01/run-aspnet-web-api-inside-your-application.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pushing a message to a database is certainly an option. A few other options could be:

1. Let nodejs server write a message to a Windows Azure Queue and have VM poll this queue.
2. Open up a TCP port on the VM and have nodejs server directly communicate with the VM on that port.

My recommendation would be to go with option 1 as it is more fault tolerant.